# hive partition by time

Tags: hive, partition, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I want to implement

```
alter table dos_sourcedata add partition (data = to_date (current_timestamp ()));
```

in hive

Run this statement at a specific time every day.
but this is always wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "this is always wrong"?

Comment: `partition_specification` must be a value, it can not be an SQL expression. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create **empty partition** using [alter table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions), use value, not expression, like this:

```
alter table mytable add partition (partition_date='2020-04-01');
```

You can create partitions dynamically when loading data using insert overwrite table partition, in this case you can use expression in the query:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert overwrite table mytable partition (partition_date)
select 
      col_1,
      ...
      col_n,
      current_date --partition column is the last one
  from ...
```

Use `current_date` instead of `to_date (current_timestamp ())`.